# Редирект в апаче с mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite, php

Здравствуйте!

Как настроить апач, чтобы, к примеру, мой сайт http://site.ru/index.php работал по чистой ссылке http://site.ru/200 или с сессией http://site.ru/200/vhjksxyufuy3fe23dv23d/ и т.п ?

Comment: тебе на [этот][1] форум, там мы подобное обсуждали :)  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=mod+rewrite&t=question

Comment: На самом деле, напишите правильнее, что конкретно нужно, из того, что вы написали, понятно только то, что вам нужен `.htaccess`, но у вас тут 2 условия, чуть больше конкретики.

Answer (score 1):

Ну на вскидку если, то примерно вот так:

```
RewriteEngine OnRewriteBase   /RewriteRule   ^index\\.php$  200
```